# OpenGL Version Support on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I try to code an OpenGL project with Qt (v5.1.1) on OS X 10.9, in the manner of the modern pipeline implementation. However I encounter some problems to rebuild programs from tutorials as e.g.
http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt

The simple triangle does not show up, however there are no warnings and the program itself shows up. I suspected that my mac might not support the GLSL. So I looked for a way to print some information. I found someone with a similar problem who did it like this.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGLFormat>
#include "glwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication mApplication(argc, argv);

    QGLFormat mGlFormat;
    mGlFormat.setVersion(3, 3);
    mGlFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
    mGlFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);

    qDebug() << "OpenGL context QFlags " << mGlFormat.openGLVersionFlags();
    qDebug() << "OpenGL context " << mGlFormat;

    GLWidget mWidget(mGlFormat);
    mWidget.show();

    qDebug() << "OpenGL context" << mWidget.format();
    qDebug() << "Driver Version String:" << glGetString(GL_VERSION);

    return mApplication.exec();
}
```

And I got as a result.

> OpenGL context QFlags  QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x8|0x10|0x20|0x40|0x1000|0x2000|0x4000|0x8000)
>
> OpenGL context  QGLFormat(options QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x20|0x80|0x200|0x400) , plane  0 , depthBufferSize  -1 , accumBufferSize  -1 , stencilBufferSize  -1 , redBufferSize  -1 , greenBufferSize  -1 , blueBufferSize  -1 , alphaBufferSize  -1 , samples  -1 , swapInterval  -1 , majorVersion  3 , minorVersion  3 , profile  1 )
>
> OpenGL context QGLFormat(options QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x20|0x80|0x200|0x400) , plane  0 , depthBufferSize  1 , accumBufferSize  -1 , stencilBufferSize  1 , redBufferSize  -1 , greenBufferSize  -1 , blueBufferSize  -1 , alphaBufferSize  -1 , samples  4 , swapInterval  -1 , majorVersion  3 , minorVersion  3 , profile  1 )
>
> Driver Version String: 0x10800e6be

Even though I am not sure about the exact meaning of this, derived from what was written at the source of this idea, it seems that the 0x8000 meant that OpenGL 3.3 is first supported but since later flags are only 0x400 the version support is lost somehow along the way.

My graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB which should support OpenGL 3.3.
https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/

- Does that mean I am not able to use the GLSL under these configurations?
- If so, is it possible to upgrade some library or graphics driver?
- What happens to applications using the core profile when started on a computer that does not support the very same?

Similar post
[Can't set desired OpenGL version in QGLWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000014/cant-set-desired-opengl-version-in-qglwidget)

Comment: C++ stream I/O annoys me. I am pretty sure that the value you are printing for the version string is the address the string points to instead of the actual string. You might need to cast it to `(const char*)` or create a `std::string`.

Comment: Just type `glxinfo` into a terminal, it'll tell you what your driver supports.

Comment: @cmannett85: The question here is not what version is supported, but what version he is actually getting. OS X will give you an OpenGL 2.1 context by default unless you use appropriate pixel format flags to get a 3.2 core context.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman: True, I get now `Driver Version String: 3.3 NVIDIA-8.18.27 310.40.05f01`

Comment: Ah, that is good. You have a 3.3 context in this case. Your problems must be due to the implementation of the shader, but definitely is not related to your GL version.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Ok that are good news but since I did not change the tutorial, what else could be the reason? Can someone try to run `svn co https://svn.theharmers.co.uk/svn/codes/public/opengl/trunk opengl` from the cited tutorial http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt?

Comment: For better debugging information, you should try the Qt OpenGL Debug Logger: http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-4/
With that you get some OpenGL driver depended messages, which are possibly performance warnings and other stuff. So it is a good way to look at all these messages at different hardware (Nvidia, AMD, Intel GPU) because every driver reports other stuff. Accumulating these messages you will get insight of your rendering pipeline behavior. (When i remember correctly Nvidia reports the missing vao binding and AMD does not care about it and renders also without that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I was not the only one struggling with this [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt), and I found the solution [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16041/#90717). Even though it is mentioned the source code of the tutorial is missing to bind the VAO.

> Add this in initializeGL before m_shader.setAttributeBuffer:

```
uint vao;

typedef void (APIENTRY *_glGenVertexArrays) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
typedef void (APIENTRY *_glBindVertexArray) (GLuint);

_glGenVertexArrays glGenVertexArrays;
_glBindVertexArray glBindVertexArray;

glGenVertexArrays = (_glGenVertexArrays) QGLWidget::context()->getProcAddress("glGenVertexArrays");
glBindVertexArray = (_glBindVertexArray) QGLWidget::context()->getProcAddress("glBindVertexArray");

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Comment: Since Qt 5.1 a wrapper for VAOs exist:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglvertexarrayobject.html